# What do I need to do to my current code to make the program run a multiplication table (using a two dimensional array)?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a Java program that uses the input value from a user to calculate and list the products of two numbers up to the entered number. Like if a user enters 2, the program should calculate the products between the two numbers (1 *1, 1*2, 2*1, 2*2) stores the products in a two-dimensional array, and list the products. I'm not sure that I totally understand arrays and so I feel as though my code is problem not right in many instances, can someone please tell me what I should do to my current code to make it work properly. Thanks in advance! :)

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class ProductTable {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputString;
    char letter = 'y'; 


    // Prompt the user to enter an integer
    while(letter != 'q') {
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: "); 
    int integer = input.nextInt();

   // Create an two-dimensional array to store products 
   int[][] m = new int[integer][3];
   for (int j = 1; j <= m.length; j++) {
      m[j][0] = input.nextInt();
      m[j][1] = input.nextInt();
      m[j][2] = input.nextInt();
   }

   // Display the number title
   System.out.print("   ");
   for (int j = 1; j <= m.length; j++)
      System.out.print("   " + j);

   System.out.println("\n--- ");

   // Display table body
    for (int i = 1; i <= m.length + 1; i++) {
       System.out.print(i);
       for (int j = 1; j <= m.length + 1; i++) {
          System.out.printf("%4d", i * j); 

       }
       System.out.println();
    }



        // Prompt the user to either continue or quit
    System.out.print("Enter q to quit or any other key to continue: ");
    String character = input.nextLine();
    inputString = input.nextLine();
    letter = inputString.charAt(0);
    }  

  }
}
```

Comment: From your description, you should only be asking the user for one number, then create array and calculate all values, which means that you should only have **one** call to `input.nextInt()` in your code. Right now, if you enters `5` as the first number, you require the user to enter 5 * 3 = 15 *more* numbers.

Comment: well right now my code for some reason won't doing anything past asking the user to enter an integer I'm not sure how to get it to recognize the rest of the code?

Comment: "(1 *1, 1*2, 2*1, 2*2)" doesn't realy clarify what you intend to do - especially 1*1. When user gives 4, what should happen? Why are 0,1,2 hardcoded in your code?

Comment: You named a variable 'integer' ?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant based on the number the user enters (which could be 4) it should take that number and multiply it by all the numbers up to that number they entered. So, if they typed 4 it should display a multiplication table with the rows and columns being from 1-4. Also I don't know I read a chapter about arrays and I got confused and so I guess that part isn't necessary (0,1,2).

Comment: Oh Should I not label a variable integer?

Comment: @nicomp Yes she did. She seems to be beginner and wants to understand programming. You could explain why it isn't a useful pactice to type hint variablenames in strong typed languages. But I see no big problem with it.

Comment: You want 4 resulting in 1*1,1*2,1*3,1*4, 2*1,2*2... , 3*1... , 4*1...4*4?

Comment: Yes, that's the goal.

Comment: As I said, the program is **waiting for you to enter 15 more numbers** (assuming you entered 5 as the first number). Nothing will happen until you enter all those numbers, because those calls to `input.nextInt()` are waiting, ..., and waiting, ..., and waiting, ..., and waiting, ..., and waiting, ...

Comment: Okay, well how can i fix that to where they don't wait for more numbers to be entered and will just take the number entered by the user and use it to multiply numbers starting from 1 all the way to itself  ( ex:1-5)?

Comment: Look for some `input.nextInt()` inside a loop.

Comment: I've added more information for your inspiration to the answer. First try to keep it as simple as possible. Then you can extend it to better fit your needs. You could even start with one loop and multiply with a constant 10.

Comment: Ok, let's do it step by step. Please write a code, that asks the user for a number. Store it into `maxNumber`. Generate a simple 1-dimensional array from 0 to maxNumber and store the index multiplied by 10. Add that code below your question with a description "first step: multiply by 10". Result should be: 0, 10, 20, 30...

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help I FINALLY figured it out!! :) The only thing I'm wanting to do now is make every number on the "title" line to have 3 dashes under them like the example in my textbook. Thank you so much for your patience and help!

Comment: If I understand your intention correctly, you could just do the `System.out.println("\n--- ");` directly below the line outputting the "title".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your multiplication table by iterating over 2 counter variables as you already did in your output

```
// Display table body
// loops running out of bounds (until m.length + 1 instead of m.length-1)
for (int i = 1; i <= m.length + 1; i++) {
   System.out.print(i);
   for (int j = 1; j <= m.length + 1; i++) { // missed to increment j here
      System.out.printf("%4d", i * j); 

   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Arrays should be based on 0, that means an array with 3 fields has the indexes 0, 1, 2. So the last index is length-1. Your condition `<=m.length+1` runs out of bounds. `index<length` will work since 2 is less than 3, but not 3 less than 3.

You have also a typo: In the inner loop you are doing an increment of `i` instead of `j`, so the loop will run infinite.

Try to create an outer and inner loop as you did, but with start index 0 and end condition `index<inputValue`. Calculate `multiTable[index1][index2] = (1+index1)*(1+index2)`.

Then do a similar loop and print the array fields. You don't need to use an array, you could output directly as you did. But you wanted to practice handling arrays.

---

Since you want to learn and understand, I don't like just to write the code. imagine an array with 3 fields having the indexes 0, 1, 2:

```
index 0 | 1 | 2
value 1 | 2 | 3
```

Now you would check the length at first, that's 3. You start with 0 and count while the counter does **not** reach the length since the zero based index is 1 below our natural order (0,1,2 vs. 1,2,3). That is the case as long the index is below the length, meaning `index<length`.

---

Try this logic (pseudo code). **To simplify the problem we include the 0** in our product table. So we get 0*0, 0*1, 0*2... Doing so, we do not have to ignore index 0 or to calculate between index 0 should represent value 1.

```
maxNumber = userInput()

outer loop idx1 from 0 to maxNumber
  inner loop idx2 from 0 to maxNumber
    array[idx1][idx2] = (idx1) * (idx2)
  end loop
end loop
```

Do the same to dump your generated array to screen.

First **get it running**. *Afterwards* you could try to alter the logic, so that it shows you only numbers from 1 to max.

Comment: hmm well I can't test if this makes it work or not because for some reason the program only asks me to enter an integer and doesn't really do anything else. Thanks, though, if I can figure out why it is doing that I will try fixing what u told me.

Comment: Basically there are problems with indexes out of bound as I already have written in the answer. First fix that issue.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how I should redo the outer and inner loops as u described? I fixed the typo and the problem with the conditions being out of bounds but it still doesn't let me do anything past typing in an integer.

Comment: I think it's time to create a new question because you rewrote the code.